# Nothing is displayed by the web server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After running the command "npm start," my React and Redux-based LinkedIn clone doesn't display anything on the web server.

As I write the header code, the LinkedIn header on the server should appear.`

file name :Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Header.css";
import HeaderOption from './HeaderOption';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import SupervisorAccountIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SupervisorAccount';


function Header() {
  return (
    <div className='header' >
      <div className='header_left' >
        <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/LinkedIn_icon.svg/2048px-LinkedIn_icon.svg.png' alt='' />
        <div className='header_search' >
          <SearchIcon />
          <input type="text" />
        </div>

      </div>
      <div className='header_right' >
        <HeaderOption Icon={HomeIcon} title="home" />
        <HeaderOption Icon={SupervisorAccountIcon} title="My Network" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Header;
```

file name : HeaderOption.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./HeaderOption.css";

function HeaderOption(Icon, title) {
  return (
    <div className='headeroption'>
      {Icon && <Icon className="headeroption_icon" />}
      <h3 className='headeroption_title'>{title}</h3>

    </div>
  );
}
export default HeaderOption;
```

file name :App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">

      {/* header */}
      <Header />
      {/* App body */}
      {/* Sidebar */}
      {/* Feed */}
      {/* Widgets */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: _"doesn't display anything on the web server"_... could you please explain what this means? Did you mean _"web **browser**"_?

Comment: React function components accept a props object as the first argument. Your `HeaderOption` component should look like `function HeaderOption ({ Icon, title }) { ... }`. There will be an error in your browser console about objects not being valid JSX (or something like that). This can be closed as a **TYPO**

Comment: function HeaderOption ({ Icon, title })  This expression resolved my issue